# Stop subdomains inheriting third-party cookies

Tags: cookies, third-party-cookies

Probably a dumb question but the issue I'm encountering is this:

**TL;DR**
I have a subdomain that seems to inherit third-party cookies from its parent domain. eg. 'dev.test.com' is inheriting cookies from 'test.com'

Now I understand that we can specify cookie domain when we set cookies ourselves in code, but the cookies that are being inherited are coming from a third-party source. How do we stop these from being inherited?

**Example**

- Company X provides an embeddable widget that provides certain functionality. It also does a bunch of stuff with cookies I have no control over. My parent site uses this widget and it works as intended on the parent site.
- A subdomain beneath the parent site links to the main site for various reasons meaning the user may visit the parent site at some point. However the 2 are unique entities and so the subdomain should not be inheriting cookies from the parent site.
- When user visits parent site, Widget X brings in all of its cookies and then when user returns to the subdomain the cookies remain as if they've come through the subdomain. This is what should not happen.